# User AD groups not returned when deployed to IIS

Tags: c#, ldap, iis-7, usergroups, adgroup

I want to authorize a page in C# web application. This page should only be accessed by a users in a particular AD group. I have the following code and it works perfectly when I run this in debug mode (IIS Express). But when I deploy it to my local IIS it doesn't work as expected. (User groups are always returned `NULL`).

```
public static List<string> GetAdGroupsForUser(string userName, string domainName = null)
{
   var result = new List<string>();

   if (userName.Contains('\\') || userName.Contains('/'))
   {
       domainName = userName.Split(new char[] { '\\', '/' })[0];
       userName = userName.Split(new char[] { '\\', '/' })[1];
   }

   using (PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName, userName, "password"))
   using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, userName))
   using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domainContext.Name)))
   {
       searcher.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectCategory=group)(member={0}))", user.DistinguishedName);
       searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
       searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");

       foreach (SearchResult entry in searcher.FindAll())
          if (entry.Properties.Contains("cn"))
             result.Add(entry.Properties["cn"][0].ToString());
    }

    return result;
}
```

I have referred to lot of answers online. But couldn't find a proper solution. Any help or lead would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enabled windows authentication in iis at the site level and rest of the are disabled:

[image]

Open the “Configuration Editor” for your app/site.

[image]

Navigate to the “system.web/authentication” section in Configuration Editor.

[image]

Set the authentication “mode” to “Windows” and save your changes.

[image]

Restart IIS to make sure your changes are applied and then test access – only users belonging to the permitted group should have access.

You could also try below code:

```
public bool AuthenticateGroup(string userName, string password, string domain, string group)
    {


        if (userName == "" || password == "")
        {
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, userName, password);
            DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
            mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(|(cn=" + userName + ")(sAMAccountName=" + userName + ")))";
            SearchResult result = mySearcher.FindOne();

            foreach (string GroupPath in result.Properties["memberOf"])
            {
                if (GroupPath.Contains(group))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException)
        {
        }
        return false;
    }
```

you could refer below link for more detail:

https://serverfault.com/questions/352647/restrict-access-to-iis-site-to-an-ad-group

https://forums.iis.net/t/1226581.aspx

https://forums.asp.net/t/2152453.aspx?Using+AD+groups+to+authorise+access+to+pages+using+IIS+Windows+Authentication+ASP+NET+Core+2+1